# How to render the valid state of a property that is validated by EmberValidations

Tags: ember.js, ember-validations

I've got a validation like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import EmberValidations from 'ember-validations';


export default Ember.Controller.extend(EmberValidations, {
  validations: {
    age: {
      presence: {message: 'Enter your age'}
    }
  },
  isAgeValid: function () {
    //some chek
  }.property('age'),

  canValidateAge: function () {
    //some check to determine if to render icons
  }.property('age')
    }
```

In my template:

```
  {{input id="age" placeholder="Age" value=age  class="form-control input-md"}}
                <span class="help-block">help</span>
              {{#if canValidateAge}}
                  <span class="{{if isAgeValid 'glyphicon-ok' 'glyphicon-remove'}} form-control-feedback glyphicon"></span>
                  <span class="field-error text-danger help-block">{{errors.age.[0]}}</span>
              {{/if}}
```

In the debugger I of course have a property called validations but I don't see any way how to use it. Also is there a way to avoid having to write this methods like is AgeValid and canValidateAge(shows no icons if in "pristine" state).

bower:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.0.2",
    "broccoli-merge-trees": "^0.2.1",
    "broccoli-static-compiler": "^0.2.1",
    "ember-cli": "0.2.5",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "0.3.3",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.0.0",
    "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.4.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "0.7.6",
    "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.1.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.0",
    "ember-cli-less": "^1.3.3",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "0.3.13",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.17",
    "ember-disable-proxy-controllers": "^0.7.0",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.2",
    "ember-validations": "^2.0.0-alpha.3"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can observe the `errors` property.

```
isAgeValid: Em.computed.gt('errors.age.length', 0)
```

If you want to show the validations only after touching the input field, I also suggest this blog post where you simply show errors only after `focusOut`:
http://www.teamrarebit.com/blog/2015/02/14/ember-inline-validation-errors

**Update:**

The missing part, by @SuperUberDuper:

> extend(EmberValidations.Mixin)

Comment: thanks but my errors object is undefined in the controller. Has ember validations failed to be initialised?

Comment: Hmm... try to output the errors object in the template like this, {{errors.age}}

Comment: If no errors occure in the developer tools and the age property can be printed using {{age}}, I suggest to debug into the presence validator of ember-validations both init and call method, to see if it is even called:  https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations/blob/master/addon/validators/local/presence.js

Comment: I had to add extend(EmberValidations.Mixin

Comment: I already thought of this, but then I checked the documentation and didn't find the Mixin Usage anywhere ... https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations#usage ... good that it's working now :-)